# Need Help altering a clone to-do list to make it log 3 outputs instead of one (javascript/html/css/JSON)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I began to change the copied code, so that instead of it being a "to-do" list that shoots out one statement at a time, I wanted to change it to shoot out 3 statements at a time and log them in a row.

I was able to add 2 more boxes, but when I press the purple button to have it run, it logs only one of the boxes and it leaves writing in the other 2 (new boxes I made) and it ends up looking like this before pressing the purple button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjlN0.png)

and this logs out as a result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9uRV.png)

just the name, but email does not and it leaves an imprint of the email and date (unlike the 'user name box')

Tried tinkering with eth code but don't understand how to manipulate it to make it show what I want and log the three things. Can you please help show me how to do this. Below are 3 files for HTML, CSS, and JS.

```js
// getting all required elements
const inputBox = document.querySelector(".inputField input");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".inputField button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todoList");
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector(".footer button");
// onkeyup event
inputBox.onkeyup = ()=>{
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting user entered value
  if(userEnteredValue.trim() != 0){ //if the user value isn't only spaces
    addBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the add button
  }else{
    addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button
  }
}


showTasks(); //calling showTask function
addBtn.onclick = ()=>{ //when user click on plus icon button
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting input field value
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo"); //getting localstorage
  if(getLocalStorageData == null){ //if localstorage has no data
    listArray = []; //create a blank array
  }else{
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData);  //transforming json string into a js object
  }
  listArray.push(userEnteredValue); //pushing or adding new value in array
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //transforming js object into a json string
  showTasks(); //calling showTask function
  addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button once the task added
}
function showTasks(){
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
  if(getLocalStorageData == null){
    listArray = [];
  }else{
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); 
  }
  const pendingTasksNumb = document.querySelector(".pendingTasks");
  pendingTasksNumb.textContent = listArray.length; //passing the array length in pendingtask
  if(listArray.length > 0){ //if array length is greater than 0
    deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the delete button
  }else{
    deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the delete button
  }
  let newLiTag = "";
  listArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    newLiTag += `<li>${element}<span class="icon" onclick="deleteTask(${index})"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></li>`;
  });
  todoList.innerHTML = newLiTag; //adding new li tag inside ul tag
  inputBox.value = ""; //once task added leave the input field blank
}
// delete task function
function deleteTask(index){
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
  listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData);
  listArray.splice(index, 1); //delete or remove the li
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray));
  showTasks(); //call the showTasks function
}
// delete all tasks function
deleteAllBtn.onclick = ()=>{
  listArray = []; //empty the array
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //set the item in localstorage
  showTasks(); //call the showTasks function
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
::selection{
  color: #ffff;
  background: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68EACC 0%, #497BE8 100%);
}
.wrapper{
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 120px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper header{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.wrapper .inputField{
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
}
.inputField input{
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.inputField input:focus{
  border-color: #8E49E8;
}
.inputField button{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 21px;
  outline: none;
  background: #8E49E8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.inputField button:hover,
.footer button:hover{
  background: #721ce3;
}
.inputField button.active{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.wrapper .todoList{
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.todoList li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.todoList li .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.todoList li:hover .icon{
  right: 0px;
}
.wrapper .footer{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.footer button{
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #8E49E8;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.footer button.active{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Support Tickets</header>

    <div class="inputField" >
      <input type="text" placeholder="Users Name" required>

      
      <input type="email" placeholder="Users Email" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Date" required>

      
      <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>

    
    <ul class="todoList">
      <!-- data are comes from local storage -->
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
      <span>You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> pending tasks</span>
      <button>Clear All</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you never used the value of `email` and `date` and hence only the `name` was being displayed.
I made a few changes to your `listArray` structure and made it an object, something like this

```
let userEnteredValue = {
  name: inputBox.value,
  email: email.value,
  date: date.value
};
```

for better understanding and code readability.
Then I made a few changes to your css to to display it in a line.

***Also i added a button in place of trash can icon because, I don't have bootstrap but you can replace the button with the icon again***

```js
const inputBox = document.querySelector(".inputField input");
      const email = document.querySelector("#email");
      const date = document.querySelector("#date");
      const addBtn = document.querySelector(".inputField button");
      const todoList = document.querySelector(".todoList");
      const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector(".footer button");
      // onkeyup event
      inputBox.onkeyup = () => {
        let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting user entered value
        if (userEnteredValue.trim() != 0) {
          //if the user value isn't only spaces
          addBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the add button
        } else {
          addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button
        }
      };

      showTasks(); //calling showTask function
      addBtn.onclick = () => {
        //when user click on plus icon button
        let userEnteredValue = {
          name: inputBox.value,
          email: email.value,
          date: date.value,
        }; //getting input field value
        console.log(userEnteredValue);
        let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo"); //getting localstorage
        if (getLocalStorageData == null) {
          //if localstorage has no data
          listArray = []; //create a blank array
        } else {
          listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); //transforming json string into a js object
        }

        listArray.push(userEnteredValue); //pushing or adding new value in array
        localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //transforming js object into a json string
        showTasks(); //calling showTask function
        addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button once the task added
      };
      function showTasks() {
        todoList.innerHTML = "";
        let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
        if (getLocalStorageData == null) {
          listArray = [];
        } else {
          listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData);
        }
        const pendingTasksNumb = document.querySelector(".pendingTasks");
        pendingTasksNumb.textContent = listArray.length; //passing the array length in pendingtask
        if (listArray.length > 0) {
          //if array length is greater than 0
          deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the delete button
        } else {
          deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the delete button
        }

        // console.log(listArray);
        listArray.forEach((element, index) => {
          let newLiTag = "";
          newLiTag = `<li>${element.name} ${element.email} ${element.date}<span class="icon" onclick="deleteTask(${index})"><button>Delete</button></span></li><br>`;
          todoList.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", newLiTag); //adding new li tag inside ul tag
        });
        // console.log(newLiTag);

        inputBox.value = "";
        email.value = "";
        date.value = ""; //once task added leave the input field blank
      }
      // delete task function
      function deleteTask(index) {
        let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
        listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData);
        console.log(listArray);
        listArray.splice(index, 1); //delete or remove the li
        localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray));
        showTasks(); //call the showTasks function
      }
      // delete all tasks function
      deleteAllBtn.onclick = () => {
        todoList.innerHTML = "";
        listArray = []; //empty the array
        localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //set the item in localstorage
        showTasks(); //call the showTasks function
      };
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      }
      ::selection {
        color: #ffff;
        background: rgb(142, 73, 232);
      }
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        /* overflow: hidden; */
        padding: 10px;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68eacc 0%, #497be8 100%);
      }
      .wrapper {
        background: #fff;
        max-width: 1200px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 120px auto;
        padding: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      .wrapper header {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      .wrapper .inputField {
        margin: 20px 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        height: 45px;
      }
      .inputField input {
        width: 85%;
        height: 100%;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
      .inputField input:focus {
        border-color: #8e49e8;
      }
      .inputField button {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 5px;
        font-size: 21px;
        outline: none;
        background: #8e49e8;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 3px;
        opacity: 0.6;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
      .inputField button:hover,
      .footer button:hover {
        background: #721ce3;
      }
      .inputField button.active {
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
      }
      .wrapper .todoList {
        max-height: 250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }

      .todoList li {
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 0 15px;
        cursor: default;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .todoList li .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: -45px;
        background: #e74c3c;
        width: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }
      .todoList li:hover .icon {
        right: 20px;
      }
      .wrapper .footer {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .footer button {
        padding: 6px 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background: #8e49e8;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        opacity: 0.6;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
      .footer button.active {
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
      }
      .todoList li {
        font-size: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        word-spacing: 250px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <header>Support Tickets</header>

      <div class="inputField">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Users Name" required />

        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Users Email" required />
        <input type="text" id="date" placeholder="Date" required />

        <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
      </div>

      <ul class="todoList">
        <!-- data are comes from local storage -->
      </ul>
      <div class="footer">
        <span>You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> pending tasks</span>
        <button>Clear All</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Since localStorage won't run in this snippet below is a output screenshot**
[image]

[image]

***Now,everyting works just as you want them to!!***

***Also your code, which I edited needs a lot of refactoring for better readability and efficiency.....***